# How to remove comma after removing string in array

Tags: java, arrays, regex

**My array:**

```
["12","empty","22"],["13","23","33"]]
```

**My regex:**

```
arr.replace("\"empty\"", "")
String[] array = arr.split("\",\"");
```

**Output**

```
["12",,"22"],["13","23","33"]]
```

What is the best way to get rid of the comma after the replace in my string array?

Comment: The split is not adding a comma, it’s always there. You’re just replacing “empty” with blank “”. It’s an array.

Comment: @Isank ya realised that after posting, the issue still applies though...

Comment: Why not first to split it by comma and then remove string from array?

Comment: how about `"\"empty\",?"`

Comment: Or, why not create a regex that will help to replace the comma (if there is one after) along with the string/text.

Comment: @Antoniossss that doesn't work because then it is looking to remove a string named "empty,?"

Comment: it wont why would it?

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried it, it acts as part of the string resulting in the string not being removed at all

Comment: Ye you tried, but you dont know that `replace` does not accept regular expressions, and regex is what I gave you. Use `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst` insteed.

Comment: @Antoniossss Got ya! my regex isn't very good so thanks for the patience and explanation. this solved my problem.

Comment: @rianskii - Be sure to accept, and/or upvote if it solved your problem There is numeric tracking of your questions (that anyone can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
    String arr="[\"12\",\"empty\",\"22\"],[\"13\",\"23\",\"33\"]]";
    System.out.println("Input: "+arr);
    System.out.println("Result: "+arr.replaceAll("\"empty\",?",""));
```

Gives

```
Input: ["12","empty","22"],["13","23","33"]]
Result: ["12","22"],["13","23","33"]]
```